# Copy file using impersonation and CopyFileEx from Kernel DLL?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-3.0

I am using the following code to copy a file to a directory where only one X user has access, I am using impersonation but when I use it the CopyFileEx does not work, but I don't know why. if I remove the part of the impersonation it works correctly but I need it to be copied with a user X since in production it has to be like that.

```
                        ImpersonationUtils impersonation = new ImpersonationUtils();
                var token = impersonation.LogonAsUser("User", "Domain", "pwd");

                if (!IntPtr.Equals(token, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = null;
                    var newIdentity = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity(token);
                    impersonatedUser = newIdentity.Impersonate();

                    bool result = CopyFileEx(filename, tempFilepath, new CopyProgressRoutine(this.CopyProgressHandler), IntPtr.Zero, cancelp, 0);

                    if (impersonatedUser != null)
                        impersonatedUser.Undo();

                    impersonation.LogonAsUserEnd(token);
                }
```

Comment: I've removed your C# 4 tag because stating that the above code is going to be compiled using version 3 of the C# language AND version 4 of the C# language doesn't make much sense. Since C# 3 is the lowest common denominator, I've left that tag. I've also removed the winforms tag since nothing in the code here seems to be UI-related.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class I wrote in the past to make operations under `Impersonation`,
Check out how the token is created inside `DoWorkUnderImpersonation()`
with the credentials and **the required constants** to `LogonUser()` of `advapi32.dll`.
The required operation is made inside the `DoWork()` method, add your copy files logic there.
Call the static method `DoWorkUnderImpersonation()` from out side

```
// Implementation of the Impersonation class
Impersonation.DoWorkUnderImpersonation("DOMAIN", "USER", "PASSWORD");


public static class Impersonation
{
    // obtains user token
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string pszUsername, string pszDomain, string pszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    // closes open handes returned by LogonUser
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    public static void DoWorkUnderImpersonation(string _domain, string _userName, string _password)
    {
        //elevate privileges before doing file copy to handle domain security
        WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
        IntPtr userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        string domain = _domain;
        string user = _userName;
        string password = _password;

        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("windows identify before impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            // if domain name was blank, assume local machine
            if (domain == "")
                domain = System.Environment.MachineName;

            // Call LogonUser to get a token for the user
            bool loggedOn = LogonUser(user,
                                        domain,
                                        password,
                                        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                                        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                                        ref userHandle);

            if (!loggedOn)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception impersonating user, error code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return;
            }

            // Begin impersonating the user
            using (impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Main() windows identify after impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                //run the program with elevated privileges (like file copying from a domain server)
                DoWork();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Exception impersonating user: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clean up
            if (impersonationContext != null)
            {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
            }

            if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(userHandle);
            }
        }
    }


    private static void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            // MAKE YOUR REQUIRED TASK HERE UNDER IMPERSONATION
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("error in Impersonation.DoWork() executing a task: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```